# PHP MySQL - limit query result by time difference

Tags: php, mysql, time, limit

This would be an example of database table:

[image]

PHP script should  limit query result between NOW and time before 30 seconds

To be clear:

In current time is `2012-03-23 03:28:00` and database is as descibed in example, resoult should be: "guest"

This is a part of PHP script.

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("db", $con);

    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table LIMIT BY ...???...... ');
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
         echo $row['username'];
        }

    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want a `LIMIT`, you want a `WHERE`

```
$result = mysql_query(
'SELECT * FROM table WHERE `timestamp` > NOW()- INTERVAL 30 SECOND '
);
```

In SQL, a `LIMIT` clause executes the whole query, and then only takes a certain "range" of consecutive rows. You can say "The first 50", or "From 20 to 30".

A `WHERE` clause limits the query on certain criteria, such as field contents. That is what you want here.

Answer (score 2):

```
... WHERE (unix_timestamp(NOW()) - unix_timestamp(timestamp))<30 ..
```

OR

```
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), timestamp))<30
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table where date_sub(now(), timestamp ) < your_time_interval ');
```